# How do I fade out this fade on mouseleave?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to be able to fade out the div that just got faded in, but I can't get it to work. I have the following code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.upgrade').mouseenter(function() {
            var modal = $(this).data('modal');
            // alert(modal);
            $('.' + modal).fadeIn(200);
        }).mouseleave(function() {
            $('.' + modal).stop().fadeOut(200);
        });
    });

    <div class="upgrade" id="upgrade-1" data-modal="bonus">
       <!-- text -->
    </div>

   <div class="bonus">
      <!-- bonus product text -->
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to delcare modal outside mouseenter function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var modal="";//declare here
    $('.upgrade').mouseenter(function() {
         modal = $(this).data('modal');
        $('.' + modal).fadeIn(200);
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        $('.' + modal).stop().fadeOut(200);
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/C4LtT/)

Answer (score 1):

I assume the mistake is not defining `modal` in the mouseleave event.

Try

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.upgrade').mouseenter(function() {
            var modal = $(this).data('modal');
            // alert(modal);
            $('.' + modal).fadeIn(200);
        }).mouseleave(function() {
            var modal = $(this).data('modal');
            $('.' + modal).stop().fadeOut(200);
        });
    });
```